# BIML CustomSsisConnection Issue - XML triple nested quote

Tags: xml, ssis, nested, biml

I'm trying to submit this custom connection from BIML to SSIS 2014:

```
<CustomSsisConnection Name="Xtract DEV" CreateInProject="1" CreationName="XTRACT" ObjectData="&lt;XtractConnectionManager ConnectionString=&quot;USER=SERVICEUSER LANG=EN MSHOST=SAPSERVER.SERVICES.DOMAIN R3NAME=DEV GROUP="Development Server" PASSWD=SERVICEPW &quot; /&gt;"/>
```

The GROUP part is where it fails "Development Server" - double quotations included. If I do it without quotations then when I run the BIML file, my created SSIS package has GROUP = Development instead of Development Server which is wrong. Placing the double quotations fails and so does the XML escape " since it is already being used and the quotation marks are supposed to be within the two " tags.

In summary the problem is:

```
<CustomSsisConnection ... ObjectData="...... ConnectionString&quot;..GROUP="Development Server" ... &quot; ..." />
```

My question is how do I get this to work? I realize this is a triple nested quote and " doesn't do the trick. So simple question: What do I replace the two "s with?

Answer (score 0):

To make the XML well-formed, all you need to do is write the " as "

Now, perhaps that will produce something that isn't well-formed according to some other (non-XML) syntax. For example, if an XML attribute is supposed to contain valid JSON, then you couldn't write

```
<x json="{&quot;connection&quot;:&quot;a=&quot;b&quot;&quot;}"/>
```

Because after XML unescaping, the attribute would be

```
{"connection":"a="b""}
```

Now the JSON rules say that nested quotes should be escaped with a backslash, so the JSON should be

{"connection":"a=\"b\""}

which means that the XML should be

```
<x json="{&quot;connection&quot;:&quot;a=\&quot;b\&quot;&quot;}"/>
```

Now in your case, without knowing something about "BMIL" or "SSIS", I don't know what the rules for the inner syntax might be: but the approach is the same: work out how the "triply nested" quotes should be escaped according to the rules of that inner syntax, and then escape the resulting string using the XML rules.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ordinary space as the string is.. Look at my Initial Catalog, it has space also, and it works fine.

Example:

```
<Connection Name="TESTSERVER" ConnectionString="Data Source=.;Initial 
Catalog=test test;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto 
Translate=False;">
```